# the issure of the react redux app after reloading or refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, optimization, redux, user-experience

As we know, the operation of reloading or refreshing the page will clear the state datas of redux store, which always leads to rendering errors because of the missing of state datas. To solve these problems, we can reFetch the datas with the parameters in query string when reloading the page or stores the old state datas of redux store which is required by this page into localStorage before reloading the page. 
Do you have a better solution? What is your preferred solution? Your share will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to refetch the data after the page is refreshed, as the state is lost.

however, you can also use `localStorage` to store some of the critical data like auth information so that user doesn't have to relogin again on refresh.

After the app is started you can get the values from `localStorage` and set the state accordingly.

You can also use `nextjs` in your application, which renders the components in the server.